# Black spots on material at lower angles

Tags: materials, lighting

I have a plane with a material that shows black spots when viewed from lower angles at rendering (preview also).
In Material Preview the problem doesn't exists.
Why does my material behaves like that?

[image: blender black spots]

Comment: hello, please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the material you're showing here is the world background (not the plane material).

Comment: Its hard to tell without seeing your material setup, but I suspect the problem has something to do with your Normal Map - either it is lacking a Normal Map Node between the Image Texture and the Normal Input, or it is set to _sRGB_ color-space instead of _Non-Color_

Comment: @ChristopherBennett thank Chris, color-space was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Set *Normal Input* to *Non-Color* instead of *sRGB*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)